# unique user login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using forms authentication to log users onto my website.

But what happens if someone is trying to login with the same details from different machines at the same time? Is there a way to check this?

Ideally, I'd like to display a message to the second attempt saying that that user account is already logged in..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold that information server-side (the list of users that are already logged in). Then, on each login, check if not already in that list.

Comment: don't forget to end or destroy all competing sessions for that account at login.

Comment: @Timothy Groote, good point, otherwise the user might not be able to login because of another "forgotten" session opened someplace else.

Comment: when you mean keep that infomation server side, you mean in a session? or db? because I don't think it will work by comparing it to a session variable...

Comment: Login info is usually kept in DB, so you can easily flag accounts logged in.

Answer (score 0):

When ever a login happens save the values of Username and Password in Sessions and after that for every login check with the already logged in values in the sessions, if matches display a message and dont allow to login.

Comment: I think using session variables will only work if the user is trying to login within the same machine. I need this to work accross multiple machines.